# Specifying multiple Domain Bases in Rocket.Chat LDAP

Tags: ldap, rocket.chat

On Rocket.Chat's LDAP configuration page, the helper text for Domain Base states that you should enter (emphasis mine):

> The fully qualified Distinguished Name (DN) of an LDAP subtree you want to search for users and groups. **You can add as many as you like**; however, each group must be defined in the same domain base as the users that belong to it. If you specify restricted user groups, only users that belong to those groups will be in scope. We recommend that you specify the top level of your LDAP directory tree as your domain base and use search filter to control access.

Problem is, I don't know how to enter more than one.

My DN looks like this:

`OU=IT,OU=Staff,DC=companyname,DC=local`

And I want the following users to also be synced:

`OU=Example,OU=Staff,DC=companyname,DC=local`

But I don't know how to add them both, as the docs aren't clear, and the source code is even less clear.

I've tried the following ways:

- Space separated
- Semicolon separated
- Ampersand (and double ampersand) separated
- Wrapping them up in an array (e.g. `["OU=Example ...", "OU=IT ..."]`) and as a JSON object
- Pipe (and double pipe) separated
- 'Plus' separated (e.g. `DC=local + OU=Example`)

But no matter what I do, it won't sync users. The logs tell me:

> Exception while invoking method 'ldap_sync_users' NoSuchObjectError: 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:   at Object.Future.wait (/snap/rocketchat-server/511/node_modules/fibers/future.js:449:15) ...

I know I can set up a group restriction so only users in a certain group will be synced, but the helper text says I can use multiple DNs, and I want to know how to use multiple DNs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [RFC-4514](https://docs.ldap.com/specs/rfc4514.txt), I discovered I should construct my DN like so:

`OU=Example+OU=IT,OU=Staff,DC=companyname,DC=local`

With the plus occurring between the two OUs I wish to add. Now my users are syncing correctly.